# Confused about why the following lyric needs the word "que"

Tags: gramática

This line comes from Marc Segui's *Si nos vamos*: "Porque me he cansa'o de que luego llores", which I roughly translated to "Because I am tired of you crying later".

My question is, why is the "que" needed in the sentence? Could it not just be "Porque me he cansa'o de luego llores"? Or even "Porque me he cansa'o cuando luego llores"? I'm a little confused here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**Porque me he cansa'o "de que" luego llores**".

*En este caso la frase esta bien construida*

---

En líneas generales lo que tu aprecias aquí, "**de que**", es un caso de lo que en Español recibe el nombre de "**Dequeísmo**", es decir, un uso indebido de la preposición "de" delante de la conjunción "que" con el que hay que tener cuidado, ya que tiene sus propias características y puede engañar.

Ejemplos.

- Incorrecto - Me alegra de que seáis felices.
- **Correcto** - Me alegra que seáis felices.
- Incorrecto - Es seguro de que nos quiere.
- **Correcto** - Es seguro que nos quiere.
- Incorrecto - Le preocupa de que aún no hayas llegado.
- **Correcto** - Le preocupa que aún no hayas llegado.
- Incorrecto - Es posible de que nieve mañana.
- **Correcto** - Es posible que nieve mañana.

Sin embargo, entre otros temas hay que tener presente que algunos verbos, cuando se usan en forma "pronominal", es decir, aquel verbo que se conjuga con un pronombre (me, te, se...), alegrarse, preocuparse, etc., sí exigen un complemento precedido de la preposición "de".

En ese caso, el uso conjunto de la preposición "**de**" y la conjunción "**que**" es obligatorio:

- **Correcto** - Me alegro de que seáis felices. (Alegrarse)
- Incorrecto - Me alegro que seáis felices.
- **Correcto** - Me preocupo de que no os falte nada. (Preocuparse)
- Incorrecto - Me preocupo que no os falte nada.

Este es el uso que aparece en la frase "Porque me he cansa'o de que luego llores". El verbo "cansar" se utiliza de forma pronominal "cansarse" - " me he cansado" (*Pretérito perfecto*).

*Diccionario panhispánico*

---

---

Could it not just be "Porque me he cansa'o de luego llores"? Or even "Porque me he cansa'o cuando luego llores"?

No exactamente, en este caso al ser un verbo "pronominal" - cansar / cansarse -, y como se ha indicado más arriba, **sí** se precede de la preposición "**de**", así la frase sería correcta;

- "**Porque me he cansa'o de que luego llores**". (Cansarse)

---

- *El verbo "**Cansar**" cuando significa "sentir cansancio o aburrimiento", es intransitivo pronominal (**cansarse**) y lleva normalmente un complemento introducido por "**de**" o "con"*.
- "**que**" *en este caso se utiliza como conjunción completiva, para la función de sujeto y de complemento. A veces, "**que**" se emplea con alguna preposición, por ejemplo en función de suplemento.

"Ella se convenció "**de que**" era importante*".

---

- *Porque me he cansado* "Cansarse **de**" + "**que**" (Preposición, como palabra invariable que se utiliza para establecer una relación de dependencia o suplemento entre dos o más palabras, la que sigue a la preposición funciona como complemento), *luego llores*.

(¿De qué te has cansado?. De (algo que hace) que luego tu llores).

---

*Para ampliar información sobre el "Dequeísmo" y conocer los demás casos y sus excepciones, en que  el uso indebido de la preposición "de" aparece delante de la conjunción "que", leer*;

Diccionario panhispánico de dudas.

https://www.rae.es/dpd/deque%C3%ADsmo

Answer (score 2):

Si después del "cansado" (o cualquier otra expresión que defina el estado de algo) viene un tiempo verbal del subjuntivo, es necesario ese "que". No obstante, si utilizas un infinitivo, no es necesario.

**INFINITIVO**

- Estoy cansado de **ver** tanta suciedad en la ciudad.
- Los vecinos están hartos de **reclamar** al Ayuntamiento la reparación de los adoquines.

**SUBJUNTIVO**

- Mi madre está cansada de **que** no **haga** la cama por las mañanas.
- Los niños están ilusionados con **que** los payasos de la televisión **vayan** a actuar en el pueblo.